# How to select DateTime.MinValue (01/01/1970) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, epoch

How can I select 1st January 1970 in MySQL?

Using `SELECT '1970-01-01'` doesn't return a valid `DateTime` object in C#.

I'd like it to return the Epoch date if `null` is returned, e.g.

```
SELECT      IFNULL(MAX(`created`), '1970-01-01') `lastcreated`
FROM        `tickets`
WHERE       `accnum` = 20088
```

Comment: So, you posted the question just to be able to post an answer?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yep, that's pretty commonplace. I searched and couldn't find an answer, so added it to SO in case someone else wants to know the same thing in the future.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: From [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), "If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.  [To encourage people to do this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/), there is a checkbox at the bottom of the page every time you ask a question."

Comment: Using the epoch as a magic value to indicate the non-existence of an explicit value would, generally, be bad practice.  Why not handle `NULL` cases in your application code?

Comment: @eggyal The equivalent code in C# would be `this.LastTicket = Query.IsDBNull(Query.GetOrdinal("lastcreated")) ? DateTime.MinValue : Query.GetDateTime("lastcreated");`. I was always taught to perform as much work as possible on the DB-layer. The actual check itself is just whether there was a ticket created today already, so 1970 is perfectly fine as a solution, e.g. `this.LastTicket = Query.GetDateTime("lastcreated")`. Yesterday would've also sufficed over 1970, although then it appears that a ticket was created yesterday, when it wasn't; this way it's clearer if the var is reused later on.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Well, I'd argue that's still not handling `NULL` values correctly, as it's again using a magic value.  Why not simply allow `this.LastTicket` to be `null` (and then properly handle the *lack* of an explicit value as required, e.g. displaying "no previous ticket" to the user instead of "1 Jan 1970")?  But this is deviating a long way from your question.  As for "do as much as possible in the DB-layer", I think that's a common mistake—business logic really doesn't belong in the database and is the bane of many a DBA's life.

Comment: @eggyal It's true that I should've used a nullable `DateTime`. I've changed the var to `DateTime? LastTicket = null;`, the SQL to `SELECT MAX(\`created\`) \`lastcreated\` ...`, the value to `this.LastTicket = Query.IsDBNull(Query.GetOrdinal("lastcreated")) ? null : (DateTime?) Query.GetDateTime("lastcreated");` and then the check it's used in to `if(this.LastTicket.HasValue && this.LastTicket.Value.Date == DateTime.Today) {...}`. I'll leave this question here though since someone may want to know the answer to the original question, for a different purpose :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(0)` to get a `DateTime` object for the date at 0 seconds after the Epoch:

```
SELECT      IFNULL(MAX(`created`), FROM_UNIXTIME(0)) `lastcreated`
FROM        `tickets`
WHERE       `accnum` = 20088
```

Comment: I get '1969-12-31 16:00:00' (because I am in California).